# Add class to grandparent when an Option tag in select is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 columns, each one has a select of a form.
I am trying to have a class "clicked" to my div that has "col-12" depending on the select item that I am currently using, and only if I chose an option. Here's the code that I have until the moment but apparently the jquery isn't being applied to my  tag, is it a default behavior?

PS: The code works when I select only the .form-control class, but I dont want this, I just want it to be applied if the user actually click on any option inside the select element.

**JQUERY:**

```
function(){
    $('.form-control option').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.col-12').addClass('clicked');
    });
}
```

**HTML**
My html has 4 columns like that (only changing the options inside each one)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 arrow--custom">
        <select class="form-control" id="room" name="room">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Nombre de chambre</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                                
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't register events on an <OPTION>. Instead, you should check for 'change' on your <SELECT>

```
function(){
    $('.form-control').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('.col-12').addClass('clicked');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just changing the "click" to "change" and using the <select> (.form-control) instead of trying to select the <option> solved the problem. I put the final code below in order to help others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're listening on the  element, and you need to liste on  instead.

When the value of the  changes, you add the class. Here's a working snippet, where the clicked class will add a red border so that it is visible:

```js
(function(){
    $('select.form-control').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('.col-12').addClass('clicked');
    });
})();
```

```css
.clicked select {
  border: red 2px solid; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 arrow--custom">
        <select class="form-control" id="room" name="room">
            <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Nombre de chambre</option>
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>                                
        </select>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much Victoria, your code works perfectly. I will just click the tick to the first comment from @ControlAltDel because his comment was really useful to help me finding the solution before.

Answer (score 0):

Applying this changes to my code, made it work:

```
function(){
    $('.form-control').on('change', function(){
        $(this).closest('.col-12').addClass('clicked');
    });
}
```